# Implement InfluxDB in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, influxdb

Is there someone which already tried to install an InfluxDB database and use it from Delphi ?

I tried from this Github :

> https://github.com/larsenbjorn/InfluxDB-Delphi

But the Demo application makes nothing.

Comment: InfluxDB has http based api to interact with it, did you try this? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/api/

Comment: I tried this, but impossible to use InfluxDB with HTTP API. I always have "unauthorized acess message". I use the last version of InfluxDB (2.1.1) and I don't understant how to use it on Windows 10. I have only influxd.exe, and when I started it, I have access to localhost:8086 and configured it with username, pwd ect... but I can't use the HTTP API... ANy idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "demo application makes nothing"?  You need to give more detail and information.  
I was able to run the Demo app using my InfluxDB instance.  I was able to create the Database, insert a record, show the databases, and show the InfluxDB version.

Comment: There are buttons to show version, create database, ect... but when U click nothing happened and nothing filled in the Memo. I'm using version 2.1 of influx. Which version are you using ?

Comment: It seems working with version 1.8.10 but I do not have access to UI from locahost:8086